# Mysql find matching rows for common field in two tables and combine fields into one row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have three tables:
Table 'A' has a number of events each with a unique id.
Table 'B' has categories which match the id of table A though there could be several matches for each id.
Table 'C' defines category names which match an id in table 'B'.
How can I get an output that shows unique events that have multiple categories listed together as opposed to each event repeated per category?

```
       Table A                  Table B              Table C
id | event | date |          id | catid             catid | cat
1     swim   1-2-16           1     11                11    slow
2     swim   1-2-16           1     12                12    med
3     run    1-3-16           1     13                13    fast
4     bike   1-5-16           2     11
5     run    1-30-16          3     12
                              3     13
                              4     12
                              5     11
```

I have this Mysql statement:

```
    SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
         FROM A, B, C
         WHERE A.id = B.id and B.catid = C.catid and DATE(date) BETWEEN "1-2-16" and "1-5-16
ORDER BY event, cat
```

Problem is the output of this statement repeats the event for each category.  I would like the output to list all categories applicable for each event as an output row. For example, "swim on 1-2-16 slow,med,fast" instead of "swim on 1-2-16 slow" "swim on 1-2-16 med" "swim on 1-2-16 fast".  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use group_concat

```
 select A.event, A,date, group_concat(C.cat)
 from A
 inner join b on a.id = b.id
 inner join b.catid = c.catid
 group by b.id;
```

Comment: In my real application I had to also do add an equivalent MAX(A.id) to the Select part.